# Issue while joining many tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have four tables :

```
products                          sizes
```

```
-----------------------------     -----------------------------------
| product_id | product_name |     | pizza_size_id | pizza_size_name |
-----------------------------     -----------------------------------
|     39     | Italyan      |     |       1       | Small           |
|     40     | Classic      |     |       2       | Medium          |
|     41     | Lamb         |     |       3       | Large           |
|     42     | Evi          |     -----------------------------------
-----------------------------
```

```
menu_details
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| id | order_details_fk | pizza_menus_fk | products_fk |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 17 |        132       |       92       |     39      |
| 18 |        132       |       92       |     40      |
| 19 |        132       |       92       |     41      |
| 20 |        132       |       92       |     42      |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

```
pizza_menus
```

```
--------------------------
| id | menu_id | size_id |
--------------------------
| 25 |    92   |    1    |
| 26 |    92   |    1    |
| 27 |    92   |    1    |
| 28 |    92   |    2    |
--------------------------
```

This is my SQL code :

```
SELECT   DISTINCT products.product_name, sizes.pizza_size_name 
FROM     products, menu_details, pizza_menus, sizes 
WHERE    products.product_id = menu_details.products_fk 
AND      menu_details.pizza_menus_fk = pizza_menus.menu_id 
AND      pizza_menus.size_id = sizes.pizza_size_id 
AND      menu_details.order_details_fk = 132
```

My desired output

```
----------------------------------
| product_name | pizza_size_name |
----------------------------------
|    Italyan   |      Small      |
|    Classic   |      Small      |
|    Lamb      |      Small      |
|    Evi       |      Medium     |
----------------------------------
```

Output that I get

```
----------------------------------
| product_name | pizza_size_name |
----------------------------------
|    Italyan   |      Small      |
|    Classic   |      Small      |
|    Lamb      |      Small      |
|    Evi       |      Small      |
|    Italyan   |      Medium     |
|    Classic   |      Medium     |
|    Lamb      |      Medium     |
|    Evi       |      Medium     |
----------------------------------
```

I know too many tables for such easy question but anyways
I really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: A foreign key should normally reference the unique key of the other table. Why does `pizza_menu_fk` refer to `pizza_menus.menu_id` instead of `pizza_menus.id`?

Comment: The reason you're getting that result is that `menu_id = 92` has both `size_id = 1` and `size_id = 2`. So all `menu_details` with `pizza_menus_fk = 92` are available in both sizes. This would be fixed if you used the `id` instead of `menu_id` as the foreign key, then you can point to specific rows in `pizza_menus` to get just one size.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, you are right sir. That was my mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AbdulAzizNurov Instead of posting the solution in the question, please add it **as an answer**; that way, you share your solution in a Q&A style (which SO is all about) :)

Comment: @Barranka Thanks for a hint. It is my first experience so I didn't know that I can answer to my own question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associations between `menu_details` and `pizza_menu` were made wrong so I chaged `menu_details` to :

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| id | order_details_fk | pizza_menus_fk | products_fk |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 17 |        132       |       25       |     39      |
| 18 |        132       |       26       |     40      |
| 19 |        132       |       27       |     41      |
| 20 |        132       |       28       |     42      |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

And here is my new SQL:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT products.product_name, sizes.pizza_size_name 
FROM     products, menu_details, pizza_menus, sizes 
WHERE    products.product_id = menu_details.products_fk 
AND      menu_details.pizza_menus_fk = pizza_menus.id 
AND      pizza_menus.size_id = sizes.pizza_size_id 
AND      menu_details.order_details_fk = 132
```